# How to resolve gsutil & /etc/nologin conflict

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gsutil

I was trying to back up /etc (to Google CP Storage) with the following command

sudo gsutil -m cp -PrZ -L gs.log /etc/ gs://my-bucket/etc/

but it terminated after copying about a dozen files with the error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/nologin'

/etc/nologin is a softlink: /etc/nologin -> /var/lib/initscripts/nologin
and /var/lib/initscripts/nologin does not exist.

Q. Can I delete /etc/nologin without ill effects?

Q. If not, is there any other suggestion?

Environment is Ubuntu 14.04 & gsutil 4.23.

TIA.

Comment: @mhouglum - I tried rsync as suggested & surprisingly the same result: $ sudo gsutil -m rsync -nPr -x "/etc/nologin" /etc/ gs://my-bucket/
Building synchronization state...
Caught non-retryable exception while listing file:///etc/: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/nologin'.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the -c option for cp, which continues upon encountering an error.

EDIT:

Just realized that you were using the -m flag, which implicitly uses -c.  There are a couple of alternatives:

- You could use the `gsutil rsync` command instead. Although this doesn't support the -Z flag you were using with your cp command, it does support the -x flag, which allows you to exclude certain files (e.g. any broken symlinks).
- If you want to use `gsutil cp`, you could find all of your broken symlinks and deal with them appropriately (e.g. delete them - I can't think of a case off the top of my head where deleting broken symlinks would cause any issues, but you may want to keep track of which ones you deleted just in case).